# Loading binary in XSLT - base64 encode

Tags: xslt, base64, saxon

We need to load an binary file and base64 encode the file including the result in the output. The binary is placed on a server and is only accessible via an URI.

I have written the below XSLT script but it only works on files placed accessible via the file system. If I insert the URI instead if the file path I naturally get an error: URI scheme is not 'file'.

Can anybody tell me how to make this code work for an URI?

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:java="java"     xmlns:file="http://expath.org/ns/file" xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/" xmlns:bin="http://expath.org/spec/binary" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xpath-default-namespace="http://rep.evenex.dk/schema/evenex/eBusiness_01">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="tiffPath">
        <xsl:value-of select="'C:/CGI_tiff_files/165238_EM37010002609.tiff'"/>
        <!--<xsl:value-of select="'https://www.dropbox.com/s/htw5ckxjfepye0y/altova.gif?dl=0'"/>-->
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="tiffBas64encoded">
        <xsl:value-of select="file:read-binary($tiffPath)"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <!--Tiff vars end-->
    <xsl:element name="root">
        <xsl:element name="base64EncodeTiff">
            <xsl:attribute name="path"><xsl:value-of select="$tiffPath"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:value-of select="$tiffBas64encoded"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 2):

For the next Saxon release I have implemented an extension function to meet this requirement. I've published the code at

https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/2369

and you can incorporate this in your application if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any way to do it without writing your own Java extension function.